# Elasticsearch Configuration using Environment Variables

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am wanting to be able to use environment variables like so.

```
cluster.name: ${ES_CLUSTERNAME}
node.name: ${ES_NODENAME}
```

But they are not working, the variables are being set correctly before Elasticsearch is started. Also very helpfully there are no logs relating to what the error could be. Logging is in DEBUG mode.

I am running the latest versions of both Java and Elasticsearch on Ubuntu 14.04.

Also tried to run it in console mode.

```
root@node7:~# sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (node).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Please update with error logs so we can suggest some help

Comment: Hi eliasah, there are no logs being produced even when in DEBUG mode as stated above :(

Comment: try to run elasticsearch in console mode

Comment: Yeah I have been doing that also. See my updated question.

Comment: I think that the command is `sudo service elasticsearch console` if you installed elasticsearch as a service

Comment: How do you know the environment variables are being set correctly?

Comment: I have echoed them in the terminal and also echoed them in /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch where they both show correctly.